# Magento: create order programatically: Configurable product issue

Tags: magento, configuration, magento-1.8

I am trying to create order programmatically.

There are configurable products having single base attribute i.e. Size. and some of configurable products have multiple (more than one) associated product having **same size** value.

Now, attempting to add **such** configurable product with particular size. But magento assigns the sibling/child/associated product which would encountered first! and hence, deserving SKU/sibling dropped to create order with.

I followed code from below links:

http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/2149

http://pravams.com/2011/11/11/magento-create-order-programmatically/

Is there any way to add config product with particular SKU ? (something like acceptable parameters in **"addProduct"** method etc).

Answer (score 1):

I face similar problem when adding configurable product to create an order/quote programmatically. You need to set `super_attribute` in option array when you add product. The value must be containing attribute which distinguishes the associated products (e.g: color, size). So, it will be something like this:

```
$buyOptions = array(
    'qty' => 1,
    'super_attribute' => array($attributeId => $attributeValue) //ex: array(131 => 53)
);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyOptions));
```

I don't know how if you want to choose associated product by their sku, but above code will work if you just want to choose particular associated product from configurable one. I believe it is the same in essence.

ps: I answer this here because in magento stackexchange it marked as duplicate (mistakenly, I think).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the child's sku, you can do :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'mysku-123');
```

If you have the size :

```
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
foreach ($childProducts as $child) {
    if ($child->getSize()==$size){
       //add the product to the order
    }
}
```

and then you loop in the children to find the size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But unfortunately what you addressed is not solution what am I looking for. :(
See for further details: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24593/magento-create-order-programatically-configurable-product-issue